# How do browsers render XML in the presence of XSL?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, browser

I am curious to how browsers render xml in the presence of xsl? Is the html file generated an actual object? If so, is there a way to grab that html using Java Servlets, plain javascript, Nodejs or Expressjs?

Comment: Why would the client-side document be accessible via the server?

Comment: There is no html "file", it's an html "view" very much like the css-styled rendering of a normal html page is a view of the original html source. The browser might have some internal representation of the html as an "object" or whatever, but that's the browser's business. There is no standard for exposing it to the outside. As a programmer, you can still peek at the DOM generated with this html view though.

Comment: Can you explain your question a little more to me. I'm still a novice at web dev. Whenever I have an xml file whether on my computer or through a  res.send command, if it links to an existing xsl file my xml file will render as html if that makes sense.

Comment: @kumesana So would I need to make some kind of program that takes in an xml and xsl file as input and write the html?

Comment: That's called a standalone XSLT generator and there are several of them out there. But I guess such a thing does the job, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers have a built-in XSLT 1.0 processor which is invoked to transform the XML using the XSLT stylesheet. In some cases the built-in XSLT processor produces a DOM tree as output, in other cases it produces lexical HTML which is then parsed to construct a DOM.

If you want to perform the same operation on the server, there are plenty of XSLT processors available that you can invoke server-side. They come with an API that allows you to invoke the transformation, and in most cases they give you a range of options over how you want to capture the output, e.g. as an in-memory DOM (or DOM-like) tree, or as lexical XML or HTML.

Check what version of XSLT you want to use. The built-in processors in the browser only support XSLT 1.0, which is a rather ancient and restricted subset of the language; later versions (XSLT 2.0 and 3.0) have become much more powerful and user-friendly.